# Trouble aligning task to includegraphics

Tags: graphics, include, tasks

I am making a paper for students and I have the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate
    \item In the figure, both \(PNO\) and \(ANB\) are straight lines, and \(AN=NB\). Prove that
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tasks}
            \task \(PA=PB,\)
            \task \(\angle PAN = \angle PBN\)
        \end{tasks}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{Circle9.png}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I wanted to do was make the (a) and (b) on the left and the image on the right but I can't seem to do this, especially with `enumerate` and `task`. Any ideas? I don't have to use `minipage` but I've tried `\vspace{-4em}` without using `minipage` but it moves the text below it up. I've also tried `\\[-4em]` but doesn't push the image up. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways: one with minipages, the other within `tasks`. in the second method, we have to set the figure depth to 0 pt, and have to compensate this with a vertical space to avoid overlapping with the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item In the figure, both \(PNO\) and \(ANB\) are straight lines, and \(AN=NB\). Prove that \\
          \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
              \begin{tasks}[item-indent=0pt]
                  \task \(PA=PB,\)
                  \task \(\angle PAN = \angle PBN\)
              \end{tasks}
          \end{minipage}
          \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
              \raisebox{-\height}[0ex]{ \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{eulercircle-sa}}
          \end{minipage}
    \item In the figure, both \(PNO\) and \(ANB\) are straight lines, and \(AN=NB\). Prove that%
          \begin{tasks}[item-indent=0pt](2)
              \task \(PA=PB,\)
              \task[]\adjustimage{valign=bottom, scale=0.5,raise= -0.9\height, set depth=1.5ex}{eulercircle-sa}
              \task \(\angle PAN = \angle PBN\)
          \end{tasks}
          \vspace{18ex}
    \item In the figure, both \(PNO\) and \(ANB\) are straight lines, and \(AN=NB\). Prove that%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very clear. I like the second method better.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[a)] \(PA=PB,\)
\item[b)] \(\angle PAN = \angle PBN\)
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{cmshcal_responsefunction}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why package `float`? Why not using package `enumitem` to do the itemize stuff?